# Slow Magento development environment

Tags: performance, magento, templates, caching, development-environment

I'm trying to develop a new menu template, but my magento webshop loads incredibly slow on my development machine. I have to disable the 'Page blocks HTML' in order to see my changes. Once i disable this cache, loading of a single page takes about 10 seconds! (With cache enabled its below a second).

My setup:

- USBwebserver running on same machine
- Core I5-3570K
- 8 GB Ram
- Samsung SSD 830
- Magento 1.9.2.1 shop with about 400 categories / 4000 products

Content hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1            localhost
```

What i've tried:

- Different servers, same effect: uniserver, wampp
- Enabled opcaching
- Repaired and optimized all tables
- disabled microsoft security essentials

Is this expected behaviour? What should i do to get acceptable loading speeds?

Comment: Given the file structure of Magento with a bazillion files to access, a USB stick probably is a non-starter. Use Virtualbox and put it on a virtual machine.

Comment: Not using a usb stick. USBwebserver is installed on SSD. Will the virtual machine improve load time compared to a install on the host system?

Comment: normally magento take that much time without caching.

Comment: In the past it was nothing like this. When the shop ran on version 1.7.0.2, it was around 2-3 seconds. On the live server there no issues with speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure following is in place :
1. Flat Product.
2. Flat Category.
3. At least have some cache switched on config cache specially( you will find few options in admin )

Comment: Already did it. Also all cache is on, accept Page blocks HTML.

Comment: reduce number of products and attributes during testing.So that DB load is less.Also check if DB queries taking time.

Answer (score 0):

When i deleted a 1000 products, the load time dropped dramatically. I've deleted some more, but the inital delete caused a significant timedrop.

Here some measurements:

- 18,7s > Original without caching for page block HTML (flat catalog / products on). It was more then i initially though.
- 4,67s > Deleted 1000 products
- 4,1s > Deleted all products

I suspect something else was going on. Perhaps something like the rewrite table was full and the deleted caused a rebuild of this table?